# Creating maven fat jar for testNG project

Tags: maven, testng, executable-jar

I am totally new to Maven. I Have a maven project(selenium project) that uses TestNG annotations. That means I do not have main method in entire project. I want to create a single fat JAR file with `mvn package`. I have gone through few articles for mvn package but could not find any relevant stuff. How can we achieve this for the projects having no main methods.

> **EDIT**

ON checking some more articles, I added below Class with main method as follow

```
public class MainTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { AnnotationTest.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
     }
}
```

Where AnnotationTest is a class where all the annotations are used.
When I run generated *one-jar.jar file from command line, I get `ClassNotFoundException:AnnotationTest` . Since it is maven project my test.class files are in **/target/test-classes**. How do I make it available in main method.

Comment: what exactly is your problem? what have you already tried? see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @drkthng: Thank you for above link. I may not have framed my query correctly. Please check Edit.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to figure this same thing out so in case anybody else winds up here, this is how I got around that problem:

I created a main class that ran all the classes in my testng.xml file like so:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Get the path to testng.xml
        String xmlPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/testng.xml";

        // Run all the tests in testng.xml
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
        suites.add(xmlPath);
        testng.setTestSuites(suites);
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

Then you can use Maven to build the fat jar for you as explained here: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

This only helps if you already have a testng.xml file though, not that it has to be named that, you just need all the classes or tests already defined in an xml, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Your Suite Name">

    <test name="TestName">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.fullyQualified.ClassName"></class>
            <class name="com.fullyQualified.ClassName2"></class>
            <class name="com.fullyQualified.ClassName3"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```